# How to make possible ActiveMQ with SSL connection encryption?

Tags: java, performance, ssl, activemq-classic

Currently my ActiveMQ is working fine with TCP connection. But i want to activate data encryption with SSL connection. 
Got one trick on internet that by adding new `<transportConnector>` we can do. but after changing, got error and my tomcat server is also not getting started.

my entry for SSL connection enable.

```
<transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?trace=true&needClientAuth=false"/>

  <amq:sslContext>
     <amq:sslContext 
           keyStore="file:${activemq.conf}/amq-server.ks" keyStorePassword="xxxx"
           trustStore="file:${activemq.conf}/amq-server.ts" trustStorePassword="xxxx"/>
     </amq:sslContext>
```

After putting the above code, ActiveMQ is not working properly. Even my tomcat server is also not getting started.